# After jQuery page reload without refresh, animation is not working

Tags: jquery

I need to get the page reload without refresh function to get the reset statement of my animation.
That's why I tried to reload

```
$('#wrapper').load('http://localhost:7002/myproj/home');
```

But, after reloading, my jQuery click functions are not working. Any Idea please? Thanks

The below is a piece of code.. I still need to give this function to other 2 div. so called div1 and div3.

```
$(".div2").mouseover(function () {
    $('#PP').attr('src', '../../Resources/Images/aa.png');
    if (cube.width() == 550) {
        $('.imageDiv').append(pp);
    }
}).mouseout(function () {
    $('#PP').attr('src', '../../Resources/Images/bb.png');
    pp.remove();
}).on("click", function (event) {
     $('.div1, .div3').on('click', function () {
           $('#cube').fadeTo("slow", 1);
           $('.imageDiv').contents(':not("#cube")').remove();
           $('#cube').animate({ width: '550px' }, 500);
           $('#wrapper').load('/myproj/home');
     });
     $('.div2').unbind('mouseout');
     $("#hp1,#hp2,#hp3,#hp4#").hide();
     $('#cube').animate({ width: '700px' }, 500).fadeTo("slow", 0.4);
     $('#cube').animate({ 'marginTop': "+=100px", 'marginLeft': "-=100px" }, 'slow', function () {
     $('.imageDiv').append(p3d);
     p3d.animate({ 'top': '-=10px' }, 'slow', function () {
     $('.imageDiv').append(plabel);
     p3d.click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation()
            p3d.show();
            plabel.show();
     }); 
     plabel.click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation()
            p3d.show();
            plabel.show();;
     }); 
     $(document).click(function () {
            $('#cube').fadeTo("slow", 1);
            $('.imageDiv').contents(':not("#cube")').remove();
            $('#cube').animate({ width: '550px' }, 500);
     }); 
     $('#wrapper').load('/myproj/home');
  }); 
  }); 
  });
```

Comment: Man or Man!! There are lot of syntax errors for sure!! forget that part!! what you are trying to achieve!! because you are binding several clicks and and unbinding inside click event!! That's really complicated!! So just tell what you want to acheive??

Comment: Sorry. I m very new in jQuery. Just a week ago, I needed to pick up.  I want to achieve the page reload without refresh or knowing the user. Big thanks.

Comment: Its ok bro.. learning is good but what is your requirement!! I will guide you in proper way!! You have lot of animations on click and all.. So just tell me your requirement..

Comment: Wanna get the page reload without refreshing the page.

Comment: what about those animations and all!! Post your html too if possible!!

Comment: It is on .cshtml file. A lots of code are there. Whatever, pls guide me the way how to get the page reload without refreshing. I believe it 'll be solved my current status. ^^

Comment: You want to reload whole page or a part of page?? and even though its cshtml need not to worry!! Post it..

Comment: It is for the whole page.

Comment: If you are reloading whole page then there is no use of doing it without refresh!!

Comment: Tried the part of page, but I couldn't achieve what I want like reloading the whole page. The main problem is my animation is not clickable after reloading the part of page. Is there any other way to go back the first state of animation when click the $(document)?

Comment: So you want to animate `#cube` on click of `.div2` right??

Answer (score 1):

Try writing your `click` function after `load` inside a `function` as below:

```
$('#wrapper').load('/myproj/home',function()
{
   $('#YourIDorClass').on('click',function(){

   });
});
```

or

wrap it with document `click` as below:

```
$(document).on('click','#YourIDorClass',function(){

});
```

One suggestion: Do not give full qualified path in your load like `http://localhost:7002/myproj/home` because the path changes when you upload it to server and it will no longer be `localhost:7002`

Comment: Current code structure is as the below. Couldn't find the place to wrap. '$(".div1,.div2").one("click", function (event) {

 ........................//did a lots of animated process there

 // to get the reset function
  $(document).click(function () {

  $('#wrapper').load('/myproj/home');
 });
});'

Comment: you have given `.one` which will bind for `one` click! Try giving `.on`

Comment: and why `document.click`?? Can you post your complete code??